# NSURL path not working, but NSString path working

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsurl, nsfilemanager

I saved an object to file and I am now trying to run a check on whether or not that file exists. I have confirmed the path of the file and concluded that the IF statement works when I hard code the path as a NSString, see first block. However, when I try saving the path as a NSURL, and convert it to an NSString so that fileManager can run it's method on it, it does not locate the file at the path. Anything that I am missing here?

LOCATES FILE HERE USING HARD CODE NSSTRING:

```
    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:employees toFile:@"/Users/xxx/Documents/employees.plist"];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSString *employeesPath = @"/Users/xxx/Documents/employees.plist";

    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:employeesPath]) {
        NSLog(@"It exists! yes!");
    }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Doesn't exist, sorry bud");
        }
```

DOES NOT LOCATE FILE USING NSURL:

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:employees toFile:@"/Users/xxx/Documents/employees.plist"];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSURL *employeesPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Users/xxx/Documents/employees.plist"];

    NSString *employeesString = [employeesPath absoluteString];

    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:employeesString]) {
        NSLog(@"It exists! yes!");
    }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Doesn't exist, sorry bud");
        }
```

**EDIT**

-- if I wanted to use the NSURL method, I could by making a function to store the path into a NSString the proper way. This ended up working:

```
NSString* getPropertyListPath() {
NSURL *documentDir = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil];
NSURL *plist = [documentDir URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"employees.plist"];
return plist.path;
```

}

Comment: If you `NSLog` the two, and you'll see that your two `NSString` aren't the same. You could use `[employeesPath path]`.

Comment: Why are you using a NSUrl as in intermediary? Caveman debugging says log the path prior to using it is things are not working. `NSLog(@"employeesString: %@", employeesString);`

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme

Comment: To answer your question, because this is the way I was taught, that I should always use NSURL to store addresses. I am still learning the in's and out's of it. Thank-you for the responses though.

Comment: Who taught you? You need to understand each line of code you write, what id does and why it is needed. When things don't work there a few time prove methods. 1. Think about what is happening. 2. Use the debugger to trace the execution and examine the variables at each step. 3 Go caveman and add temporary logging statements.

Comment: I am currently following Simon Allardice's Essentials to objC Lynda course, and decided to try out a little file check of my own in addition to one of his videos. I plan on taking what I learn from this and applying it to one of TreeHouse's iOS courses.

Comment: The problem could be that there are methods that take URLs and they are favored. But you need to look at the documentation to see if a method takes a URL or a path. The method names usually indicate which is needed. In this case the method is: `fileExistsAtPath:`, sadly there is no `fileExistsAtURL`

Comment: Thankyou for all of the input. Very silly of me to have over-looked what is actually being stored in a NSURL. Your mention below indeed is NOT a file path. Lesson learned, note taken.

Comment: Just added a solution that allowed me to keep it as a NSURL in the main part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a `NSURL` as a file path intermediary.

```
NSURL *employeesPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Users/xxx/Documents/employees.plist"];
NSString *employeesString = [employeesPath absoluteString];
NSLog(@"employeesString: %@", 'employeesString');
```

Output:

> employeesString: 'file:///Users/xxx/Documents/employees.plist'

Which is clearly not a file path.

Comment: FYI - If you do have a file URL, use the `path` method to extra an actual file path from the URL.

Comment: Actually, I could also create a function to store the path into a NSString.

NSString* getPropertyListPath() {
    NSURL *documentDir = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil];
    NSURL *plist = [documentDir URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"employees.plist"];
    return plist.path;
}

Answer (score 1):

You are correct to use NSURL, giuseppe, instead of string literals.

NSURL is more compatible and robust than a string literal. NSURL types will give you access to more methods and functionality.

The trick that you stumbled into is that you needed the file path without the "*scheme*" or "*domain*" included in the format.

You are correct to call the `path` method on your NSURL object to retrieve the correct path format for what you need. The `path` method only returns the path component to the NSURL address path. It doesn't return the scheme or domain components.

```
  NSString *correctPathFormat = [yourNsurlObject path];
```

For Example:

If I have a file in the following directory path:

```
  NSString* myDirPath = @"/Users/yourUserName/imageFolder";
```

and load this into a NSURL object:

```
  NSURL *nsurlDirPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myDirPath];
```

then append the file name and file type:

```
  NSURL *nsurlFilePath = [nsurlDirPath URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"employee.plist"];
```

If you call the  `[nsurlFilePath absoluteString]` method you will get an NSString value in the format of "*scheme://domain/path*"

```
 NSString *retrievePath = [nsurlFilePath absoluteString];
 NSLog(@"%@",retrievePath);
```

This logs out:

```
  file:///Users/yourUserName/imageFolder/employee.plist
```

Special Note: This is the equivalent to the file path:

```
  file://localhost/Users/yourUserName/imageFolder/employee.plist
```

The "*localhost*" is just omitted because this is by default implied, so that is why you see the tripple "*///*" in "*file:///Users/...*".

"*localhost*" is an alias that refers to the local device's ip address, or in other words, the device the code is running on.

Finally, to get the correct path format you need you would run the '*path*' method on the NSURL object, which takes us back to the answer at the very beginning of my response:

```
NSString *correctPathFormat = [nsurlFilePath path];
```

This logs out the correct "*path*" component, minus the "*scheme*" & "*domain*":

```
/Users/yourUserName/imageFolder/employee.plist
```

Further Explanation:
NSURLS have three parts:

```
 scheme : [http, https, ftp, file]
 domain : [www.stackoverflow.com, localhost, ipAddress]
 path   : [/questions/26663573/, /Users/youUserName/subDirName]

 scheme |  domain |   path
  file://localhost/Users/youruserName/file.txt
```